# Where is the source code for AutoScriptWriter

Tags: autohotkey

I am using autohotkey for test now but tired with modifying the "Sleep, 100" generated by autoscriptwriter. So I decided to get the source code and see if I can modify it a little bit to fit my needs but cannot find it anyway through google.

Comment: Did you end up finding anything? I'd love to make autoscriptwriter create sleeps that were the actual time you waited rather than sleep 100.

Comment: @Matthew: no. That's what I was trying to do but I still have no solution.

Comment: I've had good results with "Do It Again". http://www.spacetornado.com/DoItAgain/ It's pretty basic but it does record the length of time you wait between clicks and key presses so it's good for quick and dirty recording of macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoScriptWriter's source code is not publicly available.